# Scrollable Pixel Tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Hi I'm looking for a way to detect how many pixels a user has scrolled down a web page ( real time) before triggering events.

I've come across this code which is the type of thing I'm after, however I need to collect the whole page rather than just a div. I can't enlarge the div to the size of the entire page because it will need to scroll on iPads/iPhones etc.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnScrollDiv (div) {
            var info = document.getElementById ("info");
            info.innerHTML = "Horizontal: " + div.scrollLeft
                            + "px<br/>Vertical: " + div.scrollTop + "px";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100px;height:200px; overflow:auto;" onscroll="OnScrollDiv (this)">
        Please scroll this field!
        <div style="height:300px; width:100px; background-color:#ccc;"></div>
        Please scroll this field!
        <div style="height:300px; width:100px; background-color:#ccc;"></div>
        Please scroll this field!
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    Current scroll amounts:
    <div id="info"></div>
</body>
```

An example of what i'm after can be found at http://www.nikebetterworld.com/ Any help will be much appreciated.

Edit: it's at the bottom of the page!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to look for in jQuery are the `scroll()` event, plus the `scrollTop()` method. You can use these to discover how far down the page the user has scrolled, and based on the value display or hide content as you need.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var currentPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
   // do something with currentPosition...
});
```

You can also apply this method to indiviual elements which have `overflow: scroll` applied to them, as well as the `window` object, as in this case.

[**Here's a fiddle to see it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/aAQ7X/)